# What file extensions can be opened with c

Tags: c

what types of file extensions can be opened with c
I know we can use .dat and .txt but what more can be used?
What types can be modified?
can I actually edit HTML, C++.
I'd like to open system 32.

Comment: The question does not make sense. You could open whatever you want, as far as you know how to interpret their data.

Comment: You can open any file (as long as permissions allow). What you do with it is another thing.

Answer (score 3):

An extension simply a convenient and conventional embellishment to a file name.

*Any* file can be opened with c (subject to permissioning).

You might want to choose between "text" and "binary" formats accordingly. But we're into specifics at this point, and such choices are down to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can open any file extension in C. Only if you have permissions. Also, Bathsbeba answer is correct, just check out [this](https://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/source/file_extensions.html) link to see what are the main types of extensions.

To open a file with any extension, do this:

```
fopen ("file.extension", "your mode");
```

You can open it in binary and text formats. If you do not know how to open in binary, this is an example:

```
fopen ("file.extension", "wb");
```

To open in `write binary` mode.